# How to add Zero before dot in Calculator Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a calculator for FreeCodeCamp in Javascript. I'm having problem with one part of the code. I'm trying to add "0" before the dot if there's no numbers, just the "0" in the screen when someone click on the "dot".

Here is my codepen link: https://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/MEQvqv

You can see it also here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var mainMath = "0";
  var subMath = "0";
  update();
  var period = /\./;
  
  $("button").click(function(){
    calculate($(this).attr("value"));
  });
  
  function calculate(keyitem) {
    switch(keyitem) {
      case "clear":
        clearScreen();
        break;
      case "plusminus":
        plusminusScreen();
        break;
      case "%":
        percentageScreen();
        break;
      case "/":
      case "*":
      case "+":
      case "-":
        addOperator();
        break;
      case "0":
      case "1":
      case "2":
      case "3":
      case "4":
      case "5":
      case "6":
      case "7":
      case "8":
      case "9":
      case ".":
        addNumber(keyitem);
        break;
      case "=":
        solveEqual();
        break;
    }
    update();
    };
 
  function clearScreen() {
     mainMath = "0";
     subMath = "0";
  };
  
  function plusminusScreen(keyitem) {
     mainMath = eval(-1 * keyitem);
  };
  
  function addNumber(keyitem) {
    if (keyitem == "."){
      if(mainMath.length == 0) {
        mainMath = "0" + keyitem;
      }
    }
    if (mainMath == "0" && subMath == "0"){
      mainMath=keyitem;
      subMath=keyitem;
      return;
    }
    mainMath+=keyitem;
    subMath+=keyitem;
    console.log(mainMath.length);
  };
  
  function update(){
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = mainMath;
  document.getElementById("history").innerHTML = subMath;
};
  
  
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400');
h1, h2, h3, p {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
html, body{
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  padding: 160px 0;
}
.calculatorbox {
  width: 260px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.calheader {
  text-align: center;
}
.calwindow {
  background: #000000;
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-direction: column; /* Safari */
  flex-direction:         column;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.entry {
  font-size: 4em;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.entryhistory {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.entry p, .entryhistory p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}
sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}
 
sub {
  bottom: -0em;
}
.row {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.key {
  width: 65px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 22px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.key.btnspan {
  width: 130px;
}
.key.topcolor {
  background: #d9d9d9;
}
.key.orange {
  background: #ff8c00;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="calheader">
      <h2>Simple Calculator</h2>
    </div>
  <div class="calculatorbox">
    <div class="calwindow">
      <!-- ENTRY BOX -->
      <div class="entry">
        <p id="answer"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="entryhistory">
        <p id="history"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- BUTTONS -->
    <div class="calbuttons">
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key topcolor" value="clear">C</button>
        <button class="key topcolor" value="plusminus"><sup>+</sup>/<sub>−</sub></button>
        <button class="key topcolor" value="%">%</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="/">÷</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key" value="7">7</button>
        <button class="key" value="8">8</button>
        <button class="key" value="9">9</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="*">×</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key" value="4">4</button>
        <button class="key" value="5">5</button>
        <button class="key" value="6">6</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="-">−</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key" value="1">1</button>
        <button class="key" value="2">2</button>
        <button class="key" value="3">3</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="+">+</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key btnspan" value="0">0</button>
        <button class="key" value=".">.</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="=">=</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The part that I'm having problem with is this:

```
function addNumber(keyitem) {
    if (keyitem == "."){
      if(mainMath.length == 0) {
        mainMath = "0" + keyitem;
      }
    }
    if (mainMath == "0" && subMath == "0"){
      mainMath=keyitem;
      subMath=keyitem;
      return;
    }
    mainMath+=keyitem;
    subMath+=keyitem;
    console.log(mainMath.length);
  };
```

What I'm trying to do is if someone press the dot ".", it should check if the numbers is already entered, if not, then add "0." I tried to check for the mainMath.length by coding it like this: `console.log(mainMath.length);`, but it didn't show anything in the console.

Comment: Screen starts with 0. When I click dot, zero is before the dot, as you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about that. While I was waiting for someone to solve this question, I managed to find the solution. It was :

```
if (keyitem == "."){
      if(mainMath == 0) {
        return mainMath = "0" + keyitem;
      }
    }
```

Now I'll have to solve the positive/negative button problem that cropped up...

Comment: Accept your own answer.

Comment: Tried, but it said to accept your own answer in 2 days... Btw, Can I ask you to help me solve the positive/negative problem or do I need to post a different question for this?

Comment: New question would be best. Update and use the same codepen.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will try to figure this out on my own first for 1 hour and if I can't solve it, I will post a new question...

Comment: Just figured it out too... :)

Comment: Thought you might.

Answer (score 0):

The technique of adding leading zeros to a value is known as padding. One option is to use [Number.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

```
var number = .5;
var paddedNumber = number.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumIntegerDigits:1})
console.log( paddedNumber );
// "0.5"
```